# warning on nginx auto start disable

Tags: services, autostart, nginx

I removed nginx from startup by running:

```
$ sudo update-rc.d -f nginx disable
```

I get the below output:

```
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `nginx' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `nginx' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
```

Are these harmless warnings or is there something I should do?

Comment: it seemed to work for me.

Comment: Too bad this was closed as "as it's unlikely to help future readers". I have the exact issue!